# Firewall -> http to https

Tags: https, firewall

I'm trying to set firewall and redirect traffic from http to https. I have a basic default rules but they block all traffic so I cannot access website. Can anyone explain me please how to set correctly firewall rules and make my website secure ? I searched a lot but nothing helped. Here is screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Your question probably would get more and/or better answers on [superuser] or [serverfault.se]. In any case you need to add details about your Firewall system and your web server (which ones are you using?). Also do you want to have a redirect (web server sends this to the browser that then requests a different page) or do you want to deliver data fetched from a https connection transparently through the unsecure http connection?